# Tracking events (via google analytics) for hashtag routes in Backbone single page app

Tags: backbone.js, google-analytics

With the [backbone.analytics.js](https://github.com/kendagriff/backbone.analytics) I'm able to track pageviews, but I have trouble in tracking events bound to different pages in My Site.

Though the events are triggered from different pages, since there is a hash tag in the URL the path after hashtag is ignored completely. Hence all the events fall under home page '/' in google analytics dashboard.

- my_domain/#page1

  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Songs','Play','track1']);
- my_domain/#page2

  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Songs','Play','track2']);

As you can see in the above example track1 and track2 belong to page1 and page2 respectively, but both track1 and track2 fall under home page '/'.

What are the possible solutions on this?

Comment: A little confused, I don't see how your events fall under the home page. Don't events use labels or categories? Are you looking for a way to insert your url like the following `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'PDF', '/salesForms/orderForm1.pdf']);` ?

Comment: When an event is tracked, by default the path in your current page URL is taken into consideration but in my case the path in URL is -  '/#/ex/page1' and latter part of hashtag - '/ex/page1'  was ignored by GA _trackEvent.

Answer (score 2):

When your page initially loads and you create the tracker object, it stores a bunch of info about the current page (e.g. title, url, screen resolution, etc.).

Then, when you send a hit to track a page view or an event or whatever, it also sends all that page data along with it. This allows you to do reporting on events per page or e-commerce actions per user, etc.

If you're creating a single page app that updates the title and/or URL as the user navigates throughout the site, you'll have to also update that tracker object prior to sending new hits. You can do that via `_gaq.push(['_set', 'page', '/new_url']);` with [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) or via `ga('set', 'page', '/new_url')'` using [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/).

Here is the documentation on the `set` method:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#set

And here's some more general information about when you should use `set`:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#set

**Note**: both of these links apply to analytics.js (Universal Analytics) rather than ga.js (Classic Analytics) as that's the recommend tracking method, but the concepts apply to both.